# How to "properly" display a list in python without brackets

Tags: python, list, printing, output, display

currently I am using

```
for s in list:
     print(*s)
```

but it displays the list output as

```
['this is']
['the output']
```

But I would like the output to be displayed as

```
this is
the output
```

There should be a simple solution but i am still yet to come across one.

Comment: `" ".join(list)`. Assuming your list is 1D and you don't want commas.

Comment: What is your input list?

Comment: Don't call a variable like a [`built-in function`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html), you make those functions inaccessible for other parts of your program.

Comment: @KentonTurner: Did any of the solution worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [['this is'], ['the output']]

for sub_list in l:
    print(sub_list[0])
```

Comment: `print(*sublist, sep = "\n")` is more flexible, because it also works with more than one sublist element.

Comment: If OP want to get the string and want to use somewhere. print might be just for debug.

Answer (score 0):

`list_string = ', '.join(list_name)`

`print (list_string) #without brackets`

Answer (score 0):

Join using the newline character:

```
print("\n".join(your_list))
```

Please note that `list` is a Python type and shouldn't be used as a variable name.

Comment: `join` is a string, not a list function. And if the OP makes a mistake like calling their variable `list`, you should point out this mistake, not repeat it.

Comment: `join` still won't work, it expects strings, not lists. I suggested testing code before posting.